# encryption in c not working

Tags: c, encryption

In the below program, I want to encrypt a sentence. However it is giving incomplete output when space comes. Any help will be highly useful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    printf("Enter a string : ");
    char c[100];
    scanf("%s",c);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if((c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')||(c[i]>'a'&&c[i]<'z'))
        {
            c[i]+=13;
            if(!(c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')||(c[i]>'a'&&c[i]<'z'))
            c[i]-=26;
        }
    }
    printf("Encrypted string is : %s\n",c);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` stops reading at whitespace, change to `fgets`:

```
fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);
```

You can skip the trailing newline using:

```
char c[100], *p;
fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);
if ((p = strchr(c, '\n')) != NULL) { 
    *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
}
```

Also, consider using

```
if (isalpha((unsigned char)c[i]))
```

instead of

```
if((c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')||(c[i]>'a'&&c[i]<'z'))
```

Don't forget to include `<ctype.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan spaces means don't use `%s` format specifier. Use `%[^\n]` format specifier, It will scan everything except New line (`\n`).

```
scanf("%[^\n]",c); // Fix 1
```

If you use `scanf` for scanning the user input, no need to append `NULL` at the end. It will be automatically added.

In loop no need to check for whole array(up to 100 characters) `for(i=0;i<100;i++)` like this, If your input is 4 or 5 character means unnecessarily it will check for remaining location so it will give you some garbage values. So limit the loop to check the user input-

```
for(i=0;c[i];i++) or for(i=0;c[i] != '\0';i++) //Fix 2
```

Both are same here. When the null character is found it will terminate the loop.

Try this code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        char c[100];
        printf("Enter a string : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]",c);
        for(i=0;c[i];i++)
        {
               if((c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')||(c[i]>'a'&&c[i]<'z'))
               {
                    c[i]+=13; 
                    if(!(c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')||(c[i]>'a'&&c[i]<'z'))
                    c[i]-=26;
               }
        }
        printf("Encrypted string is : %s\n",c);
        return 0;
}
```